# Should an experienced IT professional accept more responsibility without more pay?

Tags: salary, compensation

I've been working in the IT industry for the past 20 years and have done everything from coding to QA and system test.  I have a BS in Computer Science and currently work as a tester in a Test/QA organization.  I've been offered a position as the Team Lead (the current Lead is being promoted to another position) for the group (that supports 3 different projects) that I work in.  I don't have specific management experience but for the test project that I work on, I've been the group leader for the past year.  As Team Lead, I'd be responsible for the entire team (3 projects) and have 20 direct reports.  The Team Lead position would mean a lot more responsibility.  Should I ask for a raise and if so when?

Comment: No harm in asking, but in my experience, a lot of companies like to follow the "prove yourself in this position first and we'll increase your salary after" approach. Not a huge fan of that as an employee, but I can see why it makes sense to the employer.

Comment: I can also see why it makes sense for the employer.  But I have to look out for my own best interest, I can't assume the company will do that.  I would even be comfortable with them saying that they want me to work in the position for x period of time and then after that if my performance is satisfactory compensation will increase by x amount.  There's been no mention of this.

Comment: I would at least say something to the effect of "Hey, is ghis a formal promotion and does it put me in line gor a raise?" The answer, as thev@LaconicDroid pointed out, will probably be "if you do well in this position, it'll certainly make a raise more likely" -- but this is really a company-policy question and we can't answer it as well as your own manager can.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you want to become a team lead and deal with 20 team members and several direct and indirect bosses more than your employer wants you specifically to be the team lead. The commodity that is more in demand always commands a higher price. If your desire to become a team lead is more than your employer's desire to have you as the team lead, then the commodity you desire has a higher price and so you have to prove yourself first as a team lead for about 6 months before you ask for a raise.

If you are not interested in the team lead position unless there  is a raise, then it is better to ask about a raise before you take up the team lead position or as soon as possible if you have already taken up that position, so you can decline it right away.

Comment: I wasn't specifically interested in the Team Lead position but had told Management that I was interested in advancement.  I don't want to take on extra commitment without being compensated because it's going to seriously affect my work life balance.  In my current position I work about 50 hours per week on average.  With this new Team Lead position I estimate I'll be working  55-70 hours per week.  And I'm feeling pressured by Management to accept the position.  I get the feeling that if I don't take this position, that I won't be offered any future opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for a raise to at least put it on the radar that you know that the position is worth more than what you are currently making.  Your company would likely be happy to continue paying you what you are presently making so you are the only one to gain by bringing it up.

As to when, definitley before you take on the role.  The urgency of the situation is entirely based on when you will take on the extra responsibilities.  If you start tomorrow book a meeting with HR and your manager today.

Comment: The current Team Lead is going to be transitioning to another position so I think they want me to start within the month.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for a rise before taking the new role you need to compare your current salary to what the other team leads are getting and ask for say 10% more

Comment: @JoeStrazzere why you should aim for the rate for the Job - they promoted him/her to that role they should get the same - its unlikely that the job has formal progression based on experience

Comment: I have no idea what the current Team Leads make so I don't even know how much of an increase to ask for.